# Can I create a PhP array and then use the array name to create a new array?

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for the bad title but I couldn't figure out how to word my question and I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Can I do this/will this work:

```
<p>
 <?php
  $x=array(1,2);
  $y=array(3,4);
  $z=array($x,$y);  <-----will this work?
 ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Sure, that's legal PHP. You're basically creating a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: `$z = array_merge($x,$y);`

Comment: You try and tell us if it will work '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually creating a multi dimensional array here.

```
$x = array(1, 2);
$y = array(3, 4);
$z = array($x, $y);
```

The third array will be like this after execution of above script.

```
$z = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2
    ), 
    1 => array(
        0 => 3,
        1 => 4
    ), 
) ;
```